# How many zeros does the function $F(t)=1 - \det(\exp(tA+(1-t)B))$ have?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two real valued $n \times n$ matrix with $\operatorname{trace}(B) < 0 < \operatorname{trace}(A)$.
>   Consider the function 
>   $$F(t) = 1-\det(\exp(tA+(1-t)B))$$
>   How many zeros does this function have?

**My Efforts**

I know $\det(\exp(A)) = \exp(\operatorname{trace}(A))$ so $F$ having zeros amount to solving the equation $$\operatorname{trace}(tA+(1-t)B) = 0.$$

The argument inside $\operatorname{trace}(\,\cdot\,)$ looks to me like a parameterized equation of the path between $A$ and $B$.

Anyways the above equation reduces to $t \operatorname{trace}(A) + (1-t) \operatorname{trace}(B) = 0$. I would like to invoke the intermediate value theorem, but for that I need to show that the function from $[0,1]$ to the real numbers defined by $$t \mapsto t \operatorname{trace}(A) + (1-t) \operatorname{trace}(B)$$ is continuous.

**Edit**

Thanks to the comment below.

This function is continuous as $\operatorname{trace}(A)$ and $\operatorname{trace}(B)$ are fixed real number, so we have linear polynomial in $t$.
By the intermediate value theorem I have one zero, right?

Comment: I do not understand where you are stuck, it seems you have made the hard work. $trace(A)$ and $trace(B)$ are just real numbers. Then your last function is definitely a polynomial, thus continuous.

Comment: @nicomezi see the edit. Thanks

Comment: Why not continuous? Any linear function $ax+b$ is so

Comment: Are you assuming $t$ is real?  There are also complex zeros.

Comment: You don't need the theorem, just solve for $t=tr(B)/(-tr(A)+tr(B)).$ So there is a unique real solution.